# AWS - ECS: List cluster and their Amazon EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

Is there a way to list

- all your ecs clusters
- the ec2 instance(s) comprising each cluster?

The [aws cli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/index.html#cli-aws-ecs) does not seem to support such option.

I am trying to create an inventory of such resources and I want the above info to be recorded (ECS clusters + instance number / type of each of those instances)

Answer (score 4):

Do you have the [latest](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/blob/master/CHANGELOG.rst) `AWS CLI` installed so you have `ecs` subcommand available?

- how to list available cluster - it will return a list of clusters ARNs:

  ```
  aws ecs list-clusters
  ```
- how to get container instances of the cluster - it will return a list of container instances ARNs in the cluster:

  ```
  aws ecs list-container-instances --cluster FOOBAR
  ```
- finally, how to get EC2 instance(s) ID of the container instance(s):

  ```
  aws ecs describe-container-instances --cluster FOOBAR --container-instances FOOBAR_CLUSTER_CONTAINER_INSTANCES_ARNS
  ```

The last command will describe particular container instance(s) where you can filter out `ec2InstanceId` parameter to find out EC2 instance(s) ID.